# Equivalent Definition of Projective Cover

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

according to Rotman's text "Homological Algebra", he defines a projective cover as follows, 
[image]

Now I want to show that if an epimorphism $\epsilon$ from $P$ to $M$ where $P$ is projective, is a projective cover of $M$, then $\text{ker}(\epsilon)$ is superfluous.
I know to show this, assume that $\text{ker}(\epsilon) + N = P$ where $N \subseteq P$ a submodule, then I need to show that $N = P$ but I don't know how to proceed next using the def of projective cover.
I know I need to choose some projective module $Q$ to fit in the diagram and use it. 
 Initially, I want to choose $Q = N$ but then I need $N$ to be projective and this is ture if I know $N$ is a summand of $P$.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is simply not true.

For instance consider $\mathbb{Z\to Z/2}$ the canonical projection. Let $P$ be a projective $\mathbb Z$-module. Then it is free (projective $\mathbb Z$-modules are always free), so it's of the form $\mathbb Z^{(I)}$ for some $I$, and so any epic $\psi: P\to \mathbb Z/2$ is of the form $\bigoplus_I f_i$ where $f_i : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2$, where at least one of the $f_i$ is nonzero (and if it's nonzero, then it's the usual projection).

Therefore there is an epic lift $P\to \mathbb Z$.

However, the kernel is clearly not superfluous, as $2\mathbb Z + 3\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$.

The kernel will be superfluous if and only if *every* lift is epic, which need not be the case, as $\mathbb Z\overset{3}\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2$ shows.

For the claim where you assume *all* lifts are epic, an easy solution consists in picking a projective module $Q$ together with an epimorphism $f:Q\to N$.  It then suffices to check that $\psi := \epsilon\circ f$ is an epimorphism (check this ! this is  where you use $N+\ker(\epsilon) = P$), so that $\varphi = f$ is a lift, and by assumption it must be an epimorphism : $P=N$ (since the image of $f$ is contained in $N$ by definition)

Comment: thank you for the answer, the thing is that in Rotman's text, he wants you to show that the two definition of projective cover are equivalent, namely the definition using the diagram and the definition that states that "an epic $\epsilon: P \to M$, where $P$ is projective, is a projective cover if and only if ker($\epsilon$) is superfluous. " so when you said, it's not correct, I don't really know.

Comment: I think the mistake is in the definition using the diagram : it should be "every lift is epic"

Comment: oh, I think he did state it in the definition using the diagram, he just did not emphasize it, he said "... so that an epic dashed arrow always exists whenever $\psi$ is an epimorphism from a projective $Q$. "  Also, do you mind showing me how "every lift is epic" implies ker($\epsilon$) is superfluous?? thank you.

Comment: Well that's not a lack of emphasis, that's simply a wrong formulation. I'll edit my answer to add a proof of that different claim

Comment: I think I understand it now.  thank you for your help

Comment: This counterexample assumes that a projective cover of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ exists, but this is not true.

Comment: @Isaac : no, it proves that such a cover exists, given the definition in the picture

Comment: @Max My mistake, I had too quickly overlooked the fact that Rotman's definition is not the same as the usual definition of a cover.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the alternative definition of a cover, which automatically implies the definition given by Rotman:

> **Definition.**
>   Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a class of $R$-modules. If $M$ is an $R$-module, a morphism $\phi:F\to M$ is an $\mathcal{F}$-cover if the following two conditions hold:
>
> 1. For any map $\psi:F'\to M$ with $F'\in\mathcal{F}$ there is a $\alpha\in\text{Hom}_{R}(F',F)$  such  that $\psi = \phi\circ \alpha$.
> 2. If one sets $F'=F$ as in $(1)$, then $\alpha$ can only be chosen to be in $\text{Aut}(F)$.

Now, if you set $\mathcal{P}$ to be the class of projective covers, it can quickly be deduced that any projective cover will be projective <strike>and you therefore this is equivalent to Rotman's definition</strike>.

The other, more common definition is the following:

> **Definition** 
>   An epimorphism $\phi:P\to M$ is a projective cover if $P$ is projective and $\text{Ker}(\phi)$ is superfluous.

Therefore your question is wanting to show that a morphism $\phi:P\to M$ is a projective cover (as in the second definition) if and only if it is a $\mathcal{P}$-cover, where $\mathcal{P}$ is class of projective modules. This result is true:

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $f:P\to M$ be a morphism with  $P$ projective. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\phi$ is a $\mathcal{P}$-cover;
> 2. $\phi$ is a projective cover.

*Proof.*
The implication $(2\implies 1)$ is not very challenging. For the other direction, suppose that $P=Q+\text{Ker}(\phi)$. Then the restriction $\phi_{Q}:Q\to M$ is surjective so there is a map $\alpha:P\to Q$ such that $\phi = \phi_{Q}\circ\alpha$ since $P$ is projective, moreover one can see that $\phi = \phi\alpha$. But since $\phi$ is a $\mathcal{P}$-cover, it follows that $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $P$, but this forces $L=P$, and therefore $\text{ker}(\phi)$ is superfluous. Therefore $(1\implies 2)$ holds.

So what is a problem with the above answer? Well projective covers dont usually exist. In particular the above answer shows that $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ does not have a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-cover. This is, in fact, the exact example Rotman gives in showing that projective covers don't usually exist.

Rings over which finitely generated modules have a projective cover are called *semi-perfect* rings, while rings over which every module has a projective cover are called perfect rings. Note that being perfect is equivalent to every flat module being projective, and every module over any ring has a flat cover.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  After your def of an $\mathcal{F}$-cover, you said that just let $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}$ be the class of projective cover, then this is equivalent to Rotman's def of projective cover with the diagram, but don't you need $\alpha$ to be an epimorphism in order for that to imply the def given in Rotman? Cause in the def of $\mathcal{F}$-cover that you give, it does not require $\alpha$ to be an epimorphism.

Comment: I was hasty in assuming that Rotman's definition was equivalent to the usual one. Rotman's definition does not enable you to show that the definition of a projective cover (by diagram) is equivalent to the one using superfluous kernel. The usual definition does, and therefore I would recommend using that rather than Rotman's. In particular, the usual definition works for any class of modules, not just projective ones.

Comment: "Being perfect is equivalent to every projective module being flat" : all projective modules over any ring are flat, you probably meant something else ?

Comment: Thank you, it is the converse. This has been corrected.

Comment: @Isaac, sorry for the late comment, I thought I understood your argument but there's some part in your implication of 1 implies 2 that confuses me, first of all, since we assume $\phi $ is a $\mathcal{P}$-cover, don't you need $Q$ to be projective first of all? Also, according to the first def you give for $\mathcal{P}$-cover, shouldn't $\alpha$ go from $Q$ to $P$ instead of from $P$ to $Q$?  I'm sorry if I'm missing something here.

Comment: You obtain the map $\alpha:P\to Q$ irrespective of any property of $Q$ because $P$ is projective and $\phi_{Q}$ is an epi - here you need the projectivity of $P$. Now, you then have the map $\alpha:P\to P$ by composing with $Q\to P$ and this satisfies $\phi\alpha=\phi$. Now you can use the property of the $\mathcal{P}$-cover to show that $\alpha$ is an automorphism, hence $Q=P$.